# How to change UI5 version in BAS (Business Application Studio) or VSC (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-business-application-studio

How to change the UI5 version in the local build where you preview the fiori app? The advantage or idea behind this is to see if the library (UI5) has some issues and the same coding does behave differently in older/newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this blog post which explains step by step how that can be achieved.

Changing the UI5 version is sometimes necessary to validate if there might be some issue or different behavior in some older SAPUI5 version.

This is achieved using the Fiori Tools which comes with the installation pf  the node module ux-ui5-tooling. The ux-ui5-tooling is highly customizable and designed to support development tasks that need to be performed alongside of a running application.

More regarding a step by step description can be found here:
https://blogs.sap.com/2023/05/12/how-to-change-ui5-version-of-your-fiori-app-local-preview-in-business-application-studio-bas/

To those great mods deleting this, this link can't be broken, as this is published in the SAP community (one of the biggest IT companies in the world, I doubt that it will go bankrupt tomorrow and the knowledge is gone, and if so, no one will make use of UI5 and BAS anyway (both also SAP products....)

Answer (score 0):

search for "version" in your neo-app.json file and your ui5.yaml and change the value